# How to create an APS package which can be uploaded to plesk?

Tags: plesk, aps

I would like to my own apps to plesk. Namely, I would like to add a one click TYPO3-composer installation.

Is this even possible with APS standard? Is the APS standard the way to go? And is there any good documentation on it? The links inside the plesk documentation are outdated.